# PHP Form with java add

Tags: java, php, forms

I have a PHP page where the form can add multiple lines. However I am stuck at how to submit the form with all the line included in the submit. I am trying to build a system to add and remove stock.

[image: Form Picture]

```html
<?php

require_once("../models/config.php");

if (!securePage(__FILE__)) {
    // Forward to index page
    addAlert("danger", "Whoops, looks like you don't have permission to view that page.");
    header("Location: 404.php");
    exit();
}

setReferralPage(getAbsoluteDocumentPath(__FILE__));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Add Stock</title>

        <?php require_once("includes.php"); ?>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            </nav>

            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id='display-alerts' class="col-lg-12">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Dashboard <small>Add Stock</small></h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Stock</li>
                        </ol>

                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i> Units </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                            <label>Date</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="date"  id="date" >
                                        </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                        <label>Station</label>
                                          <select class="form-control" id="station" name="position">
                                                    <option value="0"> Please Select </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    include 'connection.php';
                                                    $supplies= "SELECT * FROM `stations` ORDER BY station";
                                                    $result_supplies= mysql_query($supplies);
                                                    while($row_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_supplies)){
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $row_supplies['id']?>"><?php echo $row_supplies['station']?></option>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">

                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="requester" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
                                        <label>Add Row</label>
                                        <input type="button" id="add-row" name="add-row" class="btn btn-success" value="+" />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="row" id="clone-row">
                                    <div class="row timesheet-row">

                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                                <label>Item</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="position" name="position">
                                                    <option value="0"> Please Select </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    include 'connection.php';
                                                    $supplies= "SELECT * FROM `supplies` ORDER BY name";
                                                    $result_supplies= mysql_query($supplies);
                                                    while($row_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_supplies)){
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $row_supplies['id']?>"><?php echo $row_supplies['name']?></option>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                                                <label>Total Removed</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="number">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <script src="../js/schedule.js"></script>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.row -->

            </div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->

        </div><!-- /#wrapper -->

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alertWidget('display-alerts');

                // Load the header
                $('.navbar').load('header.php', function () {
                    $('.navitem-dashboard').addClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before actually answering... let me make sure I'm correct.. you are trying to figure out how to send all the information in the form to your database by clicking a button, and you want to use JavaScript/jQuery... am I right? If that's the case, it's pretty simple using AJAX, by sending an XMLHttpRequest opening a PHP file that will process the data and then save it. I can show you how but please let me know before writing a whole testament as answer.

Comment: That is the jist of it. But I dont care if it is by AJAX or Java, I was thinking this is the only way to do it. I am at lost when it comes to sending each row of data.

Comment: Alright, easy peasy, but it'll take a long answer, so please give me a few minutes to write the whole code for you and explain you how it all works. I'll use AJAX (JavaScript) and an external PHP file which will do the data processing.

Comment: A few minutes became 1:50 hours. My bad, you had lots of HTML validation problems haha.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so by request since you don't mind what method I use to solve your problem, I'll go ahead with AJAX. I'll assume you already figured out how to add (or clone) your rows, so I won't cover that, but I'll explain you this easy way to send your form using AJAX that won't even reload the page.

The basics of it is that you'll create a function and add an `onclick` event to a button to trigger such function. The function will gather all the information from your input tags and select tags and all that stuff. **One important thing is to stop using mysql_* functions. Please use mysqli_* functions instead, but I'll keep your original mysql_* just because I want you to be able to simply copy and paste this for now.**

Here's the modified HTML. You'll notice I commented out the `<form>` tag because we won't need it in this case and I added an ID to each `<input>` and `<select>` because I'll have to retrieve their values using JavaScript. Also, you are using a lot of `<div>`s but I think it's much better and easier to read using a `<table>`.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<!-- <form> -->
        <div id="msg"></div> <!-- This is a div I am adding just to output a message each time you send info to the database -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="date">Date</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="date" id="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="station">Station</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="station">
                    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                    <?php    
                        include 'connection.php';
                        $supplies = "SELECT * FROM `stations` ORDER BY station";
                        $result_supplies = mysql_query($supplies);
                        while($row_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_supplies)){
                            echo '<option value="'.$row_supplies['id'].'">'.$row_supplies['station'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="requester" value=""> <!-- I don't know what to do with this one, by the way -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
                <label for="add-row">Add Row</label>
                <button id="add-row" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="clone-row">
            <div class="row timesheet-row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label for="position">Item</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="position"> <!-- Note that I'm using the 'name' attribute now instead of 'id', multiple IDs are not acceptable ;) -->
                        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                        <?php    
                            include 'connection.php';
                            $supplies = "SELECT * FROM `supplies` ORDER BY name";
                            $result_supplies = mysql_query($supplies);
                            while($row_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_supplies)){
                                echo '<option value="'.$row_supplies['id'].'">'.$row_supplies['name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                    <label for="total_removed">Total Removed</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="total_removed">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="sendData()">Save Information</button> <!-- Here's the button to send the form when you click it -->
        </div>
<!-- </form> -->
</div>
```

It's time for the JavaScript. You'll have to create a function that works dynamically no matter how many rows you add. So for those values you'll use arrays. For the rest, you'll simply search for their values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendData(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            formData = new FormData(),
            date = document.getElementById('date').value, // get the value searching by ID.
            station = document.getElementById('station').value,
            item = document.getElementsByName('position'), // you can't get the values yet because it's an array (see below).
            total_removed = document.getElementsByName('total_removed');

        // The following function will run only when the server
        // has responded to your request.

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                // Actually, here you can do whatever you want, but I'll just
                // add the message echoed by the PHP file (see below).
            }
        };

        // Next, I'm adding the values on the variables I created before (second parameter)
        // to the form and giving them a new name (first parameter, as string).

        formData.append("date", date);
        formData.append("station", station);
        for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            formData.append('item[]', item[i]); // loop through all rows and append the values as arrays.
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < total_removed.length; i++) {
            formData.append('total_removed[]', total_removed[i]);
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "save-data.php", true); // Set the file and method
        xhttp.send(formData); // Send the form
    }
</script>
```

Great, so now we have pretty much everything. Your form is ready, your JS is ready to search for values and send them to the PHP file... all you have to do is create the PHP file, in this case called `save-data.php` and is located in the same directory as this file.

Now, I don't know how you use your database nor its structure and I don't need to know it, I think you can create your own file by now because you'll only have to validate the information and then return a success message or error message, depending on the data and other stuff you might want to check.

To retrieve all the data in your PHP, use `$_POST[]` just as usual, for instance, `$_POST['date']`. For the arrays, you'll want to use something like:

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $k => $v){
    // $v[$k] is the 'item' variable value.
    // $_POST['total_removed'][$k]; is the 'total_removed' variable value related to the 'item' variable above.
    // In other words, $k is the index number for each element in the array.
}
```

Of course, you'll modify this to whatever you want it to do, for example update the database for each value. (That's why it's called `foreach`, right?).

Also, use `echo` for the output message, so don't echo anything inside the foreach, **ONLY** echo stuff for your output HTML, which will then be placed inside the `<div>` I created before.

I hope this helps and I am sorry if I made a typo or something because I had to think a lot to adapt the answer you your specific case which isn't the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply I will touch back and let you know how it goes